# Calculating the total variation of $x\sqrt{|\sin(1/x)|}$

Tags: calculus

> How can I calculate the total variation of 
>   $$h(x)=x\sqrt{\;\left|\;\sin\frac{1}{x}\;\right|\;}$$ 
>   on $\left[\dfrac{2\pi}{n+1},\dfrac{2\pi}{2n}\right]$?

$h$ is increasing on these intervals, and they are not overlapping. The solution should be 
$$\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac{2}{2\pi k}$$ 
but how does one arrive at this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that :

> The total variation of a real-valued (or more generally complex-valued) function $f$, defined on an interval $ [a,b] \subset \mathbb {R}$  is the quantity:
>   $$V_a^b(f) = \sup_P \sum_{i=0}^{n_P-1}|f(x_i+1) - f(x_1)|$$
>   where the supremum runs over the set $P = \{P=(x_0,\dots,x_{nP})|P \; \text{partition of} \; [a,b]\}$.

Now, since $h(x)$ is increasing over the interval given, you don't have to worry about all the partitions, because the supremum of this will be achieved at the "edges" of your given interval. Thus, the total variation, is :

$$V(h(x)) = \sum_{i=k}^n \Bigg| h\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{2i}\bigg) - h\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{i+1}\bigg)\Bigg|$$

The $i=k \to n$ index is used since the different partitions of this given interval will change for different values of $n$.

Can you finish the calculations now and yield the result provided ?

Comment: no I don't see how $V(h(x))=\sum_{i=k}^{n}\frac{2}{2\pi k}$